# Manipulating the time() function to allow email to be sent out

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have written a piece of code that allows an email to be sent out to all users that haven't logged in for a certain amount of time.

The HTML is:

```
<select name="criteria">
    <option value="14"<?php if("14" == $form->value("criteria")){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>14 days</option>
    <option value="28"<?php if("28" == $form->value("criteria")){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>28 days</option>
    <option value="90"<?php if("90" == $form->value("criteria")){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>3 months</option>
    <option value="180"<?php if("180" == $form->value("criteria")){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>6 months</option>
    <option value="365"<?php if("365" == $form->value("criteria")){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>1 year</option>
</select>
```

This is then received in another file and the following code takes over

```
$time = time() - ($criteria * 0 * 0 * 0);
$q = $admindb->getReminderCustomerEmail($time);
```

The database query is as follows:

```
function getReminderCustomerEmail($time){
    global $database;
    $q = "SELECT email, title, forename, surname FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE last_logged <= '$time'";
    return mysql_query($q, $database->myConnection());
}
```

The idea is that if you select 14 days, all users that haven't logged in in the last 14 days will be mailed.

At the moment, this isn't happening, it seems to just message all users.

I think the error must be in the line

```
$time = time() - ($criteria * 0 * 0 * 0);
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Why are you multiplying your `$criteria` by zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Any number* times *zero* is **always** zero.

Are you looking for `($criteria * 86400)` perhaps (to get days) then subtract *that* value from `time()`?

You can also use [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
strtotime('-' + $criteria + ' day',time());
```

Comment: I am a donut! Do you have to specify the 3 parts where I have put 0?

Comment: For readability, he probably wants ($criteria * 60 * 60 * 24) for days.  Or at least that's what I think he tried to do.

Comment: @Luke: You don't _have_ to, it's just usually common to use 86400 (seconds in a day) or 60*60*24 (60 seconds time 60 minutes times 24 hours) [which is 86400]).

Comment: Yeah I forgot to add the 60 by 60 by 24 (86400). Problem solved i imagine!

Comment: @Tremmors: 86400 isn't [readable](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbfeSImDntw#t=01m12s)? (Had to make the music references, sorry! ;p)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't 0 be subtracted from time() all the time? $criteria is being multiplied by 0...

Comment: I am a donut! Do you have to specify the 3 parts where I have put 0?

Answer (score 1):

A silly question:  1000 * 0 = ??

That's right, it is 0